# Downloading a file from SFTP Server in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi, download, sftp

I am working to download a .csv file from SFTP(Port:22) server in delphi. There are some components for this purpose but they are paid and they work with ads. I am searching for a free way. Is there any component that makes this for free or is there any way that u know to download it?

Comment: http://www.indyproject.org/kb/index.html?howdoiuseftpwithssl.htm

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.[Off Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)